# Can't update decimal field in mssql

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

When I execute this query:

```
UPDATE test_temp SET

test_temp.aut_z3 = 2.99, 
test_temp.slo_z3 = 0, 
test_temp.ita_z3 = 0

WHERE test_temp.product_id_part_1 = 10877
    AND test_temp.product_id_part_2 = 0
```

using SSMS it works. But if I try to do the same in C# using Dapper then noting happens.

It won't update the `test_temp.aut_z3` field.

C# code:

```
var sqlStatement = @"
UPDATE test_temp SET

test_temp.aut_z3 = 2.99, 
test_temp.slo_z3 = 0, 
test_temp.ita_z3 = 0

WHERE test_temp.product_id_part_1 = 10877
    AND test_temp.product_id_part_2 = 0 

";

await sqlConnection.ExecuteAsync(sqlStatement, null, null, DapperHelper.CommandTimeout);
```

I have also tried it like this, but the result is the same. Nothing happens:

```
var sqlStatement = @"
UPDATE test_temp SET

test_temp.aut_z3 = @aut_z3, 
test_temp.slo_z3 = @slo_z3, 
test_temp.ita_z3 = @ita_z3

WHERE test_temp.product_id_part_1 = @product_id_part_1
AND test_temp.product_id_part_2 = @product_id_part_2 

";

var sqlParameters = new
{
product_id_part_1 = 10877,
product_id_part_2 = 0,
aut_z3 = 2.99,
slo_z3 = 0,
ita_z3 = 0
};

await sqlConnection.ExecuteAsync(sqlStatement, sqlParameters, null, DapperHelper.CommandTimeout);
```

Any idea why?

Comment: please provide c# code you are usnig

Comment: If it's issue with c#, you need to share the code of c#. Without looking at your code nothing can be suggested

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: why `sqlParameters` when the values already hardcoded in query?

Comment: My bad. Updated too quick. Now it's correct.

Comment: What is the datatype of the field _aut_z3_?

Comment: What does "Nothing Happens" mean?

Comment: @PittsburghDBA The query executes with no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I called the `ExecuteAsync` method inside `multithreading` and the thread was closed before the `ExecuteAsync` method returned the result. 
I fixed it by replacing the `ExecuteAsync` method with the `Execute` method. The `.Wait()` didn't help nor the `getawaiter`.

Comment: Good follow-up! You may mark your own answer as Accepted to close this out, if you like.